# makeing array of repeated syntax

Tags: php

Can I make array and loop of below repeated syntax:

```
$row1=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `name_of_book` from `mytable` where  = `date_borrow`= curdate() ));
$row2=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `name_of_book` from `mytable` where  = `date_borrow`= curdate()+1 ));
$row3=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `name_of_book` from `mytable` where  = `date_borrow`= curdate()+2 ));
$row4=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `name_of_book` from `mytable` where  = `date_borrow`= curdate()+3 ));
.
.
.
.
$row50=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `name_of_book` from `mytable` where  = `date_borrow`= curdate()+49 ));
```

and how I echo name_of_book of $row23

Thanks

Comment: please edit your code in well structure

Comment: You have missing quotation marks at the end of your SQL queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that would do the trick.

```
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT name_of_book, date_borrow from mytable where date_borrow < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 50 DAY) ");

$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
    if($i>22 || $i < 41){
      echo $row["name_of_book"];
      echo $row["date_borrow"];  
     }
    $i = $i+1;
}
```